# PSQL asks for password for a specific database

Tags: postgresql, permissions, pg-hba.conf

I am hosting two different databases (`manage_invite` and `manage_invite_v49`) on the same server.

[image]

As you can see, when I try to connect them using the CLI, it demands the password for the second database only. But they are on the same server therefore the pg_hba.conf file is the same for both database. **Do you know what could the issue be?** I would like my `manage_invite_v49` db to be accessible without a password, as the first one.

Here is my pg_hba.conf file:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to connect according to the rule below

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

which says password is required. Most probably there is a line in [.pgpass](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html) which has password for `manage_invite` database only.
You can either remove `-h localhost` from command line which will use the line below;

```
local   all             all                                     trust
```

and therefore psql just wont asks for password or add a password line for `manage_invite_v49` database.

Comment: You are right! There is a line for `manage_invite` in the `.pgpass` file. I replaced `manage_invite` with an asterix (*) and it worked!